# Firebase Dynamic Links Short Links API Returning 401

Tags: axios, firebase-dynamic-links, nuxtjs

I'm using Firebase dynamic links short links API to shorten URLs in a Nuxt.js application. When I try to send a request to the API using Axios, it works and returns `200` when the application is initially started, but after some time (maybe a day or so), it starts returning `401` with the following response.

```
Request had invalid authentication credentials. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.
```

I have to restart the application to make it work again. Below are the request details.

**Short Link API**

```
https://firebasedynamiclinks.googleapis.com/v1/shortLinks?key=<key_of_my_firebase_project>
```

**Request body (JSON)**

```
{
    "dynamicLinkInfo": {
        "domainUriPrefix": "https://xxx.page.link",
        "link": "https://a.very.long/link"
    },
    "suffix": {
        "option": "UNGUESSABLE"
    }
}
```

**Response (When it works)**

```
{
    "shortLink": "https://xxx.page.link/XXXXXXXXXX",
    "previewLink": "https://xxx.page.link/XXXXXXXXXX?d=1"
}
```

What should I do to make sure I can always get a valid short link from Firebase?

Comment: any updates? I'm seeing the same 401 — haven't been able to get a 200 yet

Comment: We consulted the Firebase support team and they suggested checking the followings: 1) The deep link must match any URL patterns allow-list in the console. 2) The service account used has the 'Firebase Grow Viewer' or 'Firebase Grow Admin' role. 3) Make sure the REST API quota has not be hit (5 requests per IP per second & 200,000 requests per day). None of these suggestions worked for us, so we end up implementing our own URL shortener due to limited time.